# How to change the width of a tableplot in spotfire via ironpython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

This can be done manually by dragging the borders, but is there a way to set the width of the visualization (not the columns within the visualization) to a set width?

Answer (score 0):

I can find a Width property of a TableLayout class in the API, but it seems read only. I suggest a workaround, that is to multiply the value of each column width by a fraction representing the desired increase or decrease of table width.

The script below has two inputs:

*vis* is the table plot in question

*desired_width* is a number representing the goal width

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot, TableColumnCollection, TableColumn
table_plot = vis.As[TablePlot]()
table_columns = table_plot.TableColumns

#calculate current width
current_width=0
for tc in table_columns:
    current_width+=tc.Width

#multiply each column by a fraction of the desired vs current width ratio
factor = float(desired_width)/(float(current_width))
for tc in table_columns:
    tc.Width=tc.Width * factor
```